# viewport maximum-scale with user-scalable=no on android

Tags: android, viewport

Is there any way to set viewport with maximum-scale=0.5 and user-scalable=no? When I set user-scalable=no then android ignores maximum-scale

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work that way too.

This is what i am using. and it zooms in the page

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=240, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.4, maximum-scale=0.4, minimum-scale=0.4"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `initial-scale=0.5` instead.